# How to handle authentication popup in Selenium using javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium-webdriver in nodejs for the last few days, now I got a hectic problem that how to handle authentication popups. In java we can use 'autoit' library but in nodejs, I didnt find any proper library.